# Decrypt T-SQL log backup header and read LSN

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-backups

For some reason I need to read the LSN from the T-SQL logs backups without restoring them or even their headers (I assume even restoring only their headers will change the LSN on the database side too, but I'm not sure).

So is the T-SQL log backup files encrypted or does they have special structure? Any information as to where should I start?

Could anyone confirm or denies that restoring the header only wouldn't affect the `sys.fn_dblog` or anything else?

Comment: They are binary files. I don't think their structure is published anywhere since SQL Server is not an open source product.

Comment: I do not see a reason why "restoring headers only" will change LSN on the database side. It is not a restore operation, i.e. it does not change the actual database. If you are concerned, do it on a copy of the database.